# jQuery check if exists using empty element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to check if an element exists in jQuery using the length function, even though the element is empty?

I have an empty div `<div id="myDiv"></div>` that gets populated by AJAX when the user scrolls to a certain point on the screen, but when I try targeting the div before that point I'm getting nothing. The code I'm using is…

```
if( jQuery('#myDiv').length) {
    alert('#myDiv exists!');
} else {
    alert('#myDiv doesn\'t exist!');
}
```

but I'm wondering if the reason it isn't selecting the div is because it's empty. Does that matter when using the length function?

Comment: no it would have nothing to do with whether its empty or not. double check your selector

Comment: FYI: `.length` is a property not a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
length is a `property` and not a `function`. It should be

if( jQuery('#myDiv').length) {
    alert('#myDiv exists!');
} else {
    alert('#myDiv doesn\'t exist!');
}
```

It should be the below codes assuming you want to check whether the `div` is empty or not

```
if( jQuery('#myDiv').html().length > 0){
 // If the div is empty do this
}
else{
  // If its not empty do this
}
```

Check the [jQuery DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/length/)

**EDIT:**
Check if you have used the `if` condition inside `document ready`. Check out the fiddle

```
jQuery('#myDiv').html().length > 0
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg3ev118/2/) Link

Comment: `<0` will always return false.

Comment: Thanks all - I have updated the original post with the code but it's returning the same result whether there is a div with that id in the document or not. Is their a better way to check if an element exists or not not using jQuery?

Comment: check out the edit...in the if condition check for the "html()", it should be jQuery('#myDiv').html().length

Comment: Doh - I was using the if condition OUTSIDE of the (document).ready function. Have just moved it inside and it's all working fine. Feel so silly. Thanks for your help, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 5):

`.length` is not a method. It is a property, so remove the `()` after it.

```
if( jQuery('#myDiv').length ) {
    // If the div exists do this
} else {
    // If it doesn't do this
}
```